# LibreOffice does an unrequested delete cellc

Tags: macos, copy-paste, libreoffice

I've been using the same spreadsheet file for months to process some data from a website.  Part of the process involves copying a table from the website, pasting it into TextEdit for some edits, and then pasting the date into the spreadsheet.  It is two columns, tab-separated.

Starting **today**, on macOS 14.2.1 (23C71), Intel, with LibreOffice 7.6.2.1, every time I do the paste into the spreadsheet, the two upper cells in the pasted data are deleted and the columns move up.  This of course changes formulae (because locations change and references adjust).

I tried pasting part of it in a different cell, but the same thing happens.  Changing the separator to comma doesn't help.

I closed all applications, installed LibreOffice 7.6.4.1 and macOS 14.3 (23D56), and rebooted.  Opened the spreadsheet and Safari, got a new set of data and tried again.  Same behavior.

It did not have this problem yesterday.  I went back two weeks in backup and restored that version.  Still have the same problem.

**Suggestions?  Maybe a debug option for LibreOffice.**  I'll check the web for some such.

Comment: If it happens with different versions of macOS and LibreOffice, I would suspect other applications to interfere, the format of the text-to-be-pasted having changed, or the source on the website being formatted differently. This may require some experiments on your end to figure out.

Comment: Happened with only Safari, Textedit, and LibreOffice open.  Verified that the text was all ASCII, and I could not see any diference between that and an older text I had retained for comparison.  But it did not happen pasting different text into a new blank spreadsheet.  It does happen pasting unrelated text into the suspect spreadsheet, no matter which cell or sheet I choose as the corner of the paste.  Also happened if Safari was closed before doing the paste.

Comment: If you want others to retrace your steps, you may need to share more details, including examples of the data you are pasting (in a form others can use as well).

Comment: The only thing in common with all the incidents is the hardware, the date, and the .plists  I'm afraid I may have to trash the latter.

Comment: Maybe the website you are taking the data from has changed the way they format the data? Maybe you changed something by mistake in the target spreadsheet yesterday?

Comment: As I said, I compared it to an older retained dataset.  It hasn't changed and is all ASCII.  It's text and numbers.  I didn't record any macros nor change any formula that would explain _any_ paste of numbers or text into _any_ cell of _any_ sheet to trigger a delete of an entire row.  And it happened in a two-week old version of the spreadsheet that was working fine two days ago. I am going to uninstall LibreOffice & its support files and reinstall it via homebrew to see what happens.  If there's still a problem, I'll have to resort to perl and SQL to do my conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know the exact cause, but it was fixed after the following actions:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/LibreOffice \
       ~/Library/Preferences/org.libreoffice*.   \
       /Applications/LibreOffice.app
brew install libreoffice
```

The app version before and after was the same.  I saved a copy of `~/Library/Application Support/LibreOffice` and compared afterward.  The old one had a few files that differed and over a hundred that were not in the new one, most of them matching the pattern `…/LibreOffice/4/user/temp: lu*.tmp`

Comment: Warning: `brew` commands must run as the account that installed brew.  If you run it with `sudo` or from another account, you’ll break it and have to take several minutes fixing the owner/group/modes in several directories.  (BT;DT)